# Tell me which value from Math.max was the highest

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, max

I am using the following code to return the highest value out of a, b, c.

It does so successfully, but ontop of returning the highest value (which is a number) I would also like this to tell me WHICH variable returned the highest value. For example that variable "c" had the highest value.

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = 3

let maxReturn = Math.max(a, b, c);
console.log(maxReturn);
```

This will return 3 as the result, which is what I need, but how do I also output the actual variable that had the highest value? In this case tell me: "Highest value is 3, found in C"

Thank you!!

Comment: You would need to alter how you store the variables. With just variables, you can not reference which one.

Comment: no you don't...

Comment: Your data is not shaped correctly for your problem. You wouldn't store three values in three distinct variables if you wanted to know which value *and* which variable were largest. Instead you would use an associative container, like a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which would allow you to find the highest value, and corresponding key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With variables, it is very hard to be able to know what variable lines up with a,b,c without coding statements that will check the variables and see if it matches.

Using a format you can loop over means you have the ability to easily reference.

```js
const getMax = (data) => Object.entries(data).reduce((max, item) => max[1] > item[1] ? max : item);

var myData1 = { a: 1, b:2, c: 3};
var myData2 = { a: 4, b:2, c: 3};

console.log(getMax(myData1));
console.log(getMax(myData2));
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great, along with this suggested solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095301/finding-highest-values-amongst-javascript-variables ... both are solutions to my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

see second example for a better way.  remember indices are 0 based

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = 3

let maxReturn = Math.max(a, b, c);
if (maxReturn == 1)console.log(maxReturn,"a");
else if(maxReturn == 2)console.log(maxReturn,"b");
else if(maxReturn == 3)console.log(maxReturn,"c");



let x = [1,2,3]

maxReturn= Math.max(...x)
let index = x.indexOf(maxReturn)
console.log(maxReturn,index)
```

Comment: And when the values are dynamic? How does this help?

Comment: also, what if  `a=2, b=3, c=2`?

Comment: OP didn't ask those questions, however see second method

Comment: @DCR: Well no, the OP didn't ask that specifically.  But if you're going to get that literal, why isn't your answer just `console .log ("Highest value is 3, found in C")`??

Comment: If you're just going to use a big branching if/else/else tree, then `Math.max` is doing nothing useful here. Just replace the whole thing with `if (a>b && a>c) { console.log("Highest is A:", a) } else if (b>a && b>c) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: OP *really* didn't ask for the second method. If you're going to completely change the inputs, why change it into an array and show indexes? How is that remotely relevant to the question?